# my code is messy and wasteful of lines, how do I make my code simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

can this script be made simpler? I'm just learning about javascript, so I don't really know which syntax to use.

My HTML I have several id consisting of "doc1, doc2, doc3, .." and there is another id "icon-cek1, icon-ceck2, icon-cek3". "icon-cek" is used to display the place of a checkmark icon when the upload is successful / according to the extension that has been specified and if the file fails / doesn't match the extension will display a crossmark.

```
<label> DOcument 1</label>
<input type="file"id="doc1"/>
<label> Choose</label>
<div id="icon-cek1"></div>

<label> DOcument 2</label>
<input type="file"id="doc2" />
<label> Choose</label>
<div  id="icon-cek2"></div>

<label> DOcument 3</label>
<input type="file"id="doc3"/>
<label> Choose</label>
<div id="icon-cek3"></div>


    $.fn.checkFileType = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
      allowedExtensions: [],
      success: function () {},
      error: function () {},
    };
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
      $(this).on("change", function () {
        var value = $(this).val(),
          file = value.toLowerCase(),
          extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

        if ($.inArray(extension, options.allowedExtensions) == -1) {
          options.error();
          $(this).focus();
        } else {
          options.success();
        }
      });
    });
  };

  $("#doc1").checkFileType({
    allowedExtensions: ["pdf"],
    success: function () {
      document.getElementById("icon-cek1").className = "checkmark";
    },
    error: function () {
      document.getElementById('doc1').value='';
      document.getElementById("icon-cek1").className = "crossmark";
    },
  });

    $("#doc2").checkFileType({
    allowedExtensions: ["pdf"],
    success: function () {
      document.getElementById("icon-cek2").className = "checkmark";
    },
    error: function () {
      document.getElementById("doc2").value = "";
      document.getElementById("icon-cek2").className = "crossmark";
    },
  });

  $("#doc3").checkFileType({
    allowedExtensions: ["pdf"],
    success: function () {
      document.getElementById("icon-cek3").className = "checkmark";
    },
    error: function () {
    alert("Just PDF");
      document.getElementById("doc3").value = "";
      document.getElementById("icon-cek3").className = "crossmark";
    },
  });
```

or is there a simpler code to handle the case I have?

Comment: Snippet [link](https://jsfiddle.net/akagami45/cgvtahky/12/)

Comment: Please [edit] your question title so that it only states the task accomplished by your code. Since you are new around here, also read [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `<div>` associated with each `input` not its adjacent sibling, but its *next* sibling, you can dynamically navigate from the element being validated to its associated icon with `.nextElementSibling` calls. But your `checkFileType` isn't set up to call the success callback with a calling context of the element it's attached to, so fix that first. Change the success and error calls to:

```
options.success.call(this);
```

```
options.error.call(this);
```

and then the rest of your code simplifies to the following:

```
$('input[type="file"]').checkFileType({
    allowedExtensions: ["pdf"],
    success() {
        $(this).next().next().attr('class', 'checkmark');
    },
    error() {
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).next().next().attr('class', 'crossmark');
    },
});
```

If you're going to use jQuery, go ahead and use it instead of the native DOM methods like `getElementById` if you want, native DOM methods are a bit more verbose than jQuery's `$`.

Using the above method, you'll also be able to remove the IDs entirely from your HTML. (Numeric indexed IDs are quite a code smell anyway.)

This is a pretty simple problem though, it seems pretty odd to need to use a big library like jQuery for something this trivial. (If you're just learning JavaScript, consider focusing on learning just built-in JavaScript rather than a particular library like jQuery, which is somewhat obsolete for most things it's used for nowadays - built-in methods work just fine and are usually easier to understand in my experience)

Just as one example, rather than

```
if ($.inArray(extension, options.allowedExtensions) == -1) {
```

you can use

```
if (!options.allowedExtensions.includes(extension)) {
```